# How to find total no of answeres by individul options from tables given below?

Tags: mysql, sql

TABLE( Question)

```
| id    | question
|-------|----------------------
|1      | How many cities in California
```

TABLE( OPTION )

```
| id    | question_id| option   |
|-------|------------|----------|
|1      | 1          | 50       |
|2      | 1          | 55       |
|3      | 1          | 59       |
```

TABLE( Answer_by_users)

```
| id    | option_id  | user_id  |
|-------|------------|----------|
|1      | 1          | 1        |
|2      | 1          | 2        |
|3      | 2          | 4        |
|4      | 1          | 3        |
|5      | 2          | 1        |
|6      | 3          | 2        |
|7      | 3          | 1        |
```

I want to find total user answers by individual option_id like

```
| option_id| count_total_ans_of_users|
|----------|-------------------------|
|1         | 3                       |
|2         | 2                       |
|3         | 2                       |
```

Comment: please suggest me query

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stackoverflooooow is not here to create the query for you but to help you create your own query ;)

Comment: I use sub query with count function

Answer (score 0):

```
select option_id, count(distinct user_id) as count_total_ans_of_users
from answers_by_users 
group by option_id
order by option_id
```

You need to use `count` and then group by option_id.